# How to make combination of images responsive in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want the above five different images joined as this is header part of a webpage.

I used the lavalamp plugin and it works, but the webpage loses its responsiveness. On different devices, the header is not displayed in one line.

I tried to insert it in bootstrap. I inserted the lines of code of lavalamp CSS in bootstrap CSS file, shown here:

```
.lavaLampWithImage {
    margin-top:10px;
    position: relative;
    height: 55px;
   /* width: 734px;*/
    /*width:780px;*/
}

.lavaLampWithImage li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

.lavaLampWithImage li.back {
    background: url("res/arrow.png") no-repeat right -30px;
    z-index: 0;
    padding-top:59px;
    padding-left:40px;
    position: absolute;
}

.lavaLampWithImage li.back .left {
    background: url("res/arrow.png") no-repeat top left;
    height: 30px;
}

.lavaLampWithImage li a {
    z-index: 20;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mm {
    border:0px; 
}

#navbar {
    /*margin-left:152px;*/  
    /*padding-top:60px;*/
    padding-top:1px;
    /*width:727px;*/
}
```

And the relevant HTML code part is as follows:

```
<div class="span6">
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul class="lavaLampWithImage" id="1">
            <li><a href="index.html"><img class="mm" src="res/1.png" width="300" height="60" alt="home" onClick="location.href='index.html'"/></a></li> 
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html"><img class="mm" src="res/Home-n.png" width="120" height="60" alt="home" onClick="location.href='index.html'"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://eywaz.com/sit2/MTA-2Website21-02/mta"><img class="mm" src="res/blog.png" width="120" height="60" alt="contact us" onClick="location.href='http://eywaz.com/sit2/'"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="help.html"><img class="mm" src="res/Help-n.png" width="120" height="60" alt="about us" onClick="location.href='help.html'"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.html"><img class="mm" src="res/Contact_us-n.png" width="120" height="60" alt="contact us" onClick="location.href='contactus.html'"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

How to make it responsive?

Please reply as early as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make a demo in jsfiddle, images width and height are too big...

Answer (score 1):

First remove specific width and height from your image tag like bellow :

```html
<li><a href="index.html"><img class="mm" src="res/Home-n.png"  alt="home" onClick="location.href='index.html'"/></a></li>
```

Then write in css :

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:720px){
    .lavaLampWithImage li img {
        max-width:100%;
    }
}
```

and give a specific width of `li` element in percentage in this media query.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you mean with responsive images. But if you just want to resize the images according to the screen width, you could try something like this:

```
.lavaLampWithImage {
    margin:10px 0 0;
    padding:0;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
}
.lavaLampWithImage li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    background-color:green;
    width:15.38%;
}
.lavaLampWithImage li:first-child {
    width:38.45%;
}
.lavaLampWithImage li a, .lavaLampWithImage li a img {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

and the  html:

```
<div class="span6">
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul class="lavaLampWithImage" id="nav1">
            <li><a href="index.html"><img class="mm" src="http://www.upsdell.com/BrowserNews/img/ban_300x60.png" alt="home" onClick="location.href='index.html'"/></a></li><li class="current"><a href="index.html"><img class="mm" src="http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/img/banner-120x60.gif" alt="home" onClick="location.href='index.html'"/></a></li><li><a href="http://eywaz.com/sit2/MTA-2Website21-02/mta"><img class="mm" src="http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/img/banner-120x60.gif" alt="contact us" onClick="location.href='http://eywaz.com/sit2/'"/></a></li><li><a href="help.html"><img class="mm" src="http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/img/banner-120x60.gif" alt="about us" onClick="location.href='help.html'"/></a></li><li><a href="contactus.html"><img class="mm" src="http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/img/banner-120x60.gif" alt="contact us" onClick="location.href='contactus.html'"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7t7zQ/1/)

Comment: if you use `inline-block` is sensitive to spaces between li in the html (I had no spaces between lis, see my markup and jsfiddle), you can set `display:block; float:left;` instead of `display:inline-block;` on the li elements ... should work as well (http://jsfiddle.net/7t7zQ/2/) and will not be sensitive to spaces. And about image heights ...you can play a bit more with the percentages you assign to the li elements (I updated them in the answer and jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7t7zQ/2/) ... if the ul is set to 100% the li need to be the right fraction of this, which is not a whole number.

Comment: i tested it on my comps and it resizes allright on mac (ff 20, safari 6.0.3, chrome 26, opr 12.15) and windows (ff 20, chrome 26, ie 9), the wider image can render a bit off while resizing (you could try fixing that by using different sizes, so that you don't need to round percentages ... like 400 and 150 instead of 300 and 120).